# How to retrieve the username of a connection being received into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database in SQL server with 2 users connecting to it : UserA and UserB.

I have a program in C# that logs into SQL Server with a username and password for this database.

I have a Windows Form with fields:

- User
- LastName
- Surname ...etc

I want delete fields on the form and retain the user who deleted the data.

How do I retrieve the user connecting to the database?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add a user automatically when they log in - if they do not already exist?

Comment: NO.The user exist in database.I have 2 database. Database login with username an password, and database Data with user, names, auto .... I want to know who is the user that insert data in table. The username that login and insert data to appear in user from database Data after insert.

Comment: Okay, when inserting, you want to know 'who' is inserting the data? Is this a Windows App or a Web App?

Comment: Yes. Correct. Windows APP i use.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give you details about how to get the user for the C# application (i.e. the user account logged into windows). If, however, you are logging into the *database* as AAA or BBB, and you want to know what account is logged in on the Database, then you can use `SYSTEM_USER`

```
Select SYSTEM_USER
```

This gives you the user that is logged into the database. If you are using integrated security (windows authentication) to connect, this will be the domain user account (e.g. `CONTICO\John.Doe`). If you log in via a database login, it will give you that login (e.g. `sa`)

You can then use that in your insert

```
Insert into [Table] (UserName) Values (SYSTEM_USER)
```

Comment: Does this give you the identity of the user connecting to the DB, or the user on the other side of the connection? (I ask as this scenario may not work when the user/password is in a connection string, and not using SSPI)

Comment: I tried it using both integrated and by providing login credentials (via SqlCmd), via integrated it gave my domain login, when providing db credentials, it provides the username I supplied to log in.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user's name from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

See the [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the user name from the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) context.

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name;
INSERT INTO tblName (..., UserName) Values (..., userName)
```

or for a windows Application..

```
var userName = Environment.UserName; 
INSERT INTO tblName (..., UserName) Values (..., userName)
```

Comment: @user3665806, I can't make any sense of that comment?

Comment: Sorry. I use var userName = Environment.UserName; This insert in database, name for my PC.

Comment: So, that's worked OK?

Comment: No. I want to know 'who' is inserting the data from database not for PC-Name ?